# Using MathKernel without echoing a window

Tags: kernel-startup

I use M9 under windows 7 on a command prompt as:
MathKernel -noprompt -script file.m

On execution, there is a like a kernel window opened and then closed immediately. How can I avoid this window and run my script in silence? thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a Mathematica, but an operation system issue.

There are several ways on windows to avoid the cmd window showing up:

1) batch file:

```
@echo off
start /B MathKernel -noprompt -script file.m
```

2) WSScript file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("MathKernel -noprompt -script file.mt", 0, True)
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I'd go with the first example (using /MIN instead of /B will run your MathKernel, but with a minimized window, which can be helpful, if you need to have a look on logs etc.)

On Windows 7 you have a decent shell (PowerShell) you can script your MathKernel call in a .ps1 script and run it with:

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file c:\path\to\you\ps1script.ps1
```

**Edit**:

With the powershell approach you need to sign your script in order to be allowed to execute it. Either you sign it really or just add this option to the `powershell.exe` call:

```
-ExecutionPolicy ByPass
```

Hope this helps.